# JS Promise: calling a function that has a return statement inside resolve

Tags: javascript, promise

I have a function responsible for uploading images to remote storage.

I also have another function that creates a user in a DB. During the user creation, I should upload the image, get back the URL of the uploaded image, and add it to the user object before adding it to the database. However, I am stuck at getting back the urls:

My function that uploads images:

```
export const writePicture = (picture) => {
    if (picture !== undefined) {

       //code to upload image to database (...)

                .then((url) => {
                    console.log(`finished executing writePicture, url: ${url}`) //all good here, url is console logged.
                    return url;
                });
        });
    } else {
        console.log("finished executing writePicture")
        return ""
    };
}
```

The above function is exported to another file where I use promises. My promises are currently set as follows:

```
//pictureLogo and pictureImage are existing image objects

const waitForLogoUrl = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(writePicture(pictureLogo));
});

const waitForImageUrl = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  resolve(writePicture(pictureImage));
});

Promise.all([waitForLogoUrl, waitForImageUrl]).then((urls) => {
  //urls should be an array containing the urls from first and second promise
  console.log("the urls are:");
  console.log(urls);
});
```

The above is not working as expected. Inside `urls`, I am getting an array of two undefined entries instead of the two obtained urls.

`writePicture()` is working fine, it is uploading the pictures and console logging the urls. However the urls are being console logged after the `Promise.all` has finished:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RenRs.jpg

I am new to using promises so I am probably missing something about how to call a function inside a resolve. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I guess it does to some extent but there are many examples there and I wouldn't have found my way around it myself. Thank you for the suggestion though, it is a good resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when `new Promise` appears in code, it's a red flag, and this is no exception. Below I assume you *cannot* use async/await, and it only corrects 2 things:

1. Return promises from writePicture
2. Don't unnecessarily wrap its result in another promise.

```js
export const writePicture = (picture) => {
    if (picture !== undefined) {
      return codeToUploadImage(...)   // Return is critical here
         .then((url) => {
            console.log(`finished executing writePicture, url: ${url}`) //all good here, url is console logged.
            return url;
         });
    } else {
        console.log("finished executing writePicture")
        return ""
    };
}


//pictureLogo and pictureImage are existing image objects

const waitForLogoUrl = writePicture(pictureLogo);
const waitForImageUrl = writePicture(pictureImage);

Promise.all([waitForLogoUrl, waitForImageUrl]).then((urls) => {
  //urls should be an array containing the urls from first and second promise
  console.log("the urls are:");
  console.log(urls);
})
```

Comment: Since I am new to Promises (literaly just learned it today to write the above), why is it a red flag? Is there another way to use them without using the `new Promise` constructor? Thank you

Comment: @Ghadir [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743) `writePicture` already *should* return a promise. Wrapping it into another promise is not very useful. The only issue here seems to be that `writePicture` returns a non-promise on failure (when the input is `undefined`). If the function returns a promise either way, then there is no use for the Promise constructor.